# Date Range Picker in Xamarin forms Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Is there a way to create a custom control for date picker where the user can select two dates in xamarin forms. I don't think that is possible with a Xamarin date picker since it contains one date at a time.

Note: It can be achieved through syncfusion plugins, but it requires a license, therefore I want to create a custom control for android and ios.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way to create a custom control" - yes,of course there is, as evidenced by the fact that Syncfusion has done it.  There are numerous third party calendar controls that might support this, or could be modified to support it.

Comment: @Mars Yes, the Telerik calendar is one that can meet your requirement.